# How can I see the SQL that will be generated by a given ActiveRecord query in Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to see the SQL statement that a given ActiveRecord Query will generate.  I recognize I can get this information from the log after the query has been issued, but I'm wondering if there is a method that can be called on and ActiveRecord Query.

For example:

```
SampleModel.find(:all, :select => "DISTINCT(*)", :conditions => ["`date` > #{self.date}"], :limit => 1, :order => '`date`', :group => "`date`")
```

I would like to open the irb console and tack a method on the end that would show the SQL that this query will generate, but not necessarily execute the query.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When last I tried to do this there was no official way to do it. I resorted to using the function that `find` and its friends use to generate their queries directly. It is private API so there is a huge risk that Rails 3 will totally break it, but for debugging, it is an ok solution.

The method is `construct_finder_sql(options)` (`lib/active_record/base.rb:1681`) you will have to use `send` because it is private.

**Edit**: `construct_finder_sql` [was removed in Rails 5.1.0.beta1](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9f4e98330b3a7f85a4bca91fca062106ffbee2bf).

Comment: This is close to what I'm thinking.  I guess a person could write a plugin that would do something like:

    SampleModel.find(:all, :select => "DISTINCT(*)", :conditions => ["`date` > #{self.date}"], :limit => 1, :order => '`date`', :group => "`date`").show_generated_sql

and have this call the construct_finder_sql method.

Comment: With DataMapper you could because it doesn't run the query right away.  ActiveRecord on the other hand executes the query immediately.  `show_generated_sql` will be acting on an already retrieved dataset from `find`.

Comment: In Rails 3 `construct_finder_sql` is indeed removed

Answer (score 198):

Similar to penger's, but works anytime in the console even after classes have been loaded and the logger has been cached:

For Rails 2:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_variable_set :@logger, Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

For Rails 3.0.x:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

For Rails >= 3.1.0 this is already done by default in consoles.  In case it's too noisy and you want to **turn it off** you can do:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil
```

Comment: This isn't working for me in `rails console`.  Does it work only for irb loaded directly from the shell?  (or was it removed for rails 3?)

Comment: They moved it to a more sensible place for Rails 3... see my updated version.

Comment: Is there any way to do this automatically every time I start the console? Something like a before load hook?

Comment: @stream7..I dont know if u need this now, but you can move this code to `environment.rb`..`if "irb" == $0;ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT);end`..got this from comments in [http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/1/8/watching-activerecord-do-it-s-thing](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/1/8/watching-activerecord-do-it-s-thing)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: how to show the sql for a particular query while debugging without running the query.

Answer (score 110):

Stick a `puts query_object.class` somewhere to see what type of object your working with, then lookup the docs.

For example, in Rails 3.0, scopes use `ActiveRecord::Relation` which has a `#to_sql` method. For example:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :frequently_contacted, where('messages_count > 10000')
end
```

Then, somewhere you can do:

```
puts Contact.frequently_contacted.to_sql
```

Comment: Why is this answer not upvoted? For Rails 3 it's a way better answer - you can get the results of any AR::Relation statement just by putting ".to_sql" at the end. This question also provides that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814738/how-can-i-get-sql-statement-created-by-activerecordfind-without-actually-execut

Comment: Beware: you won't get all the SQL  if you have an `includes` in your relation

Comment: @BarryKelly Why is that?

Comment: @VishnuNarang I believe it's because `includes` requires multiple queries.

Answer (score 44):

just use `to_sql` method and it'll output the sql query that will be run. it works on an active record relation.

```
irb(main):033:0> User.limit(10).where(:username => 'banana').to_sql
=> "SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."username" = 'banana'
LIMIT 10"
```

when doing `find`, it won't work, so you'll need to add that id manually to the query or run it using where.

```
irb(main):037:0* User.where(id: 1).to_sql
=> "SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1"
```

Answer (score 28):

This may be an old question but I use:

```
SampleModel.find(:all,
                 :select => "DISTINCT(*)",
                 :conditions => ["`date` > #{self.date}"], 
                 :limit=> 1, 
                 :order => '`date`',
                 :group => "`date`"
                 ).explain
```

The `explain` method will give quite a detailed SQL statement on what its going to do

Comment: It'll also run the query, which might not be what people want, just for the record.

Answer (score 13):

This is what I usually do to get SQL generated in console

```
-> script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.1.2)
>> ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new STDOUT
>> Event.first
```

You have to do this when you first start the console, if you do this after you have typed some code, it doesn't seem to work

Can't really take credit for this, found it long time ago from someone's blog and can't remember whose it is.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was Jamis Buck's blog: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/1/8/watching-activerecord-do-it-s-thing

Comment: I'm not sure if it's due to Rails 2.3 or something in my environment, but this doesn't work for me.  See my response below.

Comment: This is a great solution IMO.

Answer (score 10):

Create a .irbrc file in your home directory and paste this in:

```
if ENV.include?('RAILS_ENV') && !Object.const_defined?('RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER')
  require 'logger'
  RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER = Logger.new(STDOUT)
end
```

That will output SQL statements into your irb session as you go.

EDIT: Sorry that will execute the query still, but it's closest I know of.

EDIT: Now with arel, you can build up scopes/methods as long as the object returns ActiveRecord::Relation and call .to_sql on it and it will out put the sql that is going to be executed.

Comment: This is what I've been doing, but I'm more interested in simply seeing the projected SQL the ActiveRecord query will generate.  I'm surprised there's no simple way to do this...

Answer (score 6):

My typical way to see what sql it uses is to introduce a "bug" in the sql, then you'll get an error messages spit out to the normal logger (and web screen) that has the sql in question.  No need to find where stdout is going...

Comment: Spectacular but quickest solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the [show_sql plugin](http://github.com/radar/sql_display). The plugin enables you to print the SQL without running it

```
SampleModel.sql(:select => "DISTINCT(*)", :conditions => ["`date` > #{self.date}"], :limit => 1, :order => '`date`', :group => "`date`")
```

Comment: Looks like that the link got broken (404 error). Probably, Ryan Bigg deleted the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use to_sql() function with the active record

```
Form.where(status:"Active").to_sql
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change the connection's log method to raise an exception, preventing the query from being run.

It's a total hack, but it seems to work for me (Rails 2.2.2, MySQL):

```
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class AbstractAdapter
      def log_with_raise(sql, name, &block)
        puts sql
        raise 'aborting select' if caller.any? { |l| l =~ /`select'/ }
        log_without_raise(sql, name, &block)
      end
      alias_method_chain :log, :raise
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3 you can add this line to the config/environments/development.rb

```
config.active_record.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

It will however execute the query.  But half got answered :