# How to show SQL queries run in the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When I run queries (e.g. `MyModel.where(...)` or `record.associated_things`) in the console, how can I see the actual database queries being run so I can gain more understanding of what is happening?

Comment: Andrew, if you need also to run commands in broweser you can use https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/rails_db

Comment: See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1576221/446106

Answer (score 356, accepted):

## Rails 3+

Enter this line in the console:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

## Rails 2

Enter this line in the console:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_variable_set :@logger, Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed. Have any recommendation where to go find small tricks such as these are documented?

Comment: Sure. http://slash7.com/2006/12/21/secrets-of-the-rails-console-ninjas/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123494/whats-your-favourite-irb-trick Plus http://railscasts.com/ is always good.

Comment: This works for rails 3+ but not 2, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1576221 if you're there still :)

Comment: And to disable it again: 
`ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil`

Comment: I've been here so many times, when I type "rails" in chrome, it displays this page as the top result

Answer (score 52):

In Rails 3+ you can use ActiveRecord::Relation’s [`to_sql`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-to_sql) method:

```
User.where(:id => 3).to_sql
#=> "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE \"users\".\"id\" = 3"
```

Answer (score 44):

There is the `.explain` method in Rails 4.
(`.to_sql` works too, but won't show includes)

```
Category.includes(:products).explain
=> EXPLAIN for: SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" 0|0|0|SCAN TABLE categories

EXPLAIN for: SELECT "categories_products".* FROM "categories_products" WHERE "categories_products"."category_id" IN (1, 2) 0|0|0|SCAN TABLE categories_products

EXPLAIN for: SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) 0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE products USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) 0|0|0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
```

Comment: It took me so much time to find the `.explain` will do the job and not `.to_sql`. And `.explain` still does not provide sql query in raw format which I can run in pg console. But I needed the raw query to explain and analyze. I guess will have to do with explain for now.

Answer (score 19):

I just wanted to give our production console the same behavior I’m used to on dev, where all SQL queries are reported to the console.

`Rails.logger.level = 0`

```
3.0.3 :001 > Rails.logger.level = 0
 => 0
3.0.3 :002 > User.last
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<User:…>
```

Comment: Equivalent to `Rails.logger.level = :debug`

Answer (score 12):

Starting from Rails 6 there is more convenient approach: simply add `ActiveRecord::Base.verbose_query_logs = true` in console and you will see all SQL calls and places where it was called. More info https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#verbose-query-logs

Comment: There should be no need to turn it on, anymore, as it should be nowadays on by default: "Verbose query logs are enabled by default in the development environment logs after Rails 5.2."

Comment: This seems to be deprecated: "ActiveSupport::DeprecationException: DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveRecord::Base.verbose_query_logs= is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 7.1."

Comment: This method has indeed been deprecated, but it was [moved out of `AR::Base`](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/c3f43075a3c70c3b11717741426ec38a8d3cd14a) and is now available as `ActiveRecord.verbose_query_logs` as of Rails 7.0.

Answer (score 6):

As from recently, you can use this:

https://github.com/dejan/rails_panel

It consists of developer console panel add-on for chrome, and gem file which needs to be added to your application's **Gemfile** like this:

```
group :development do
  gem 'meta_request'
end
```

Then run again:

```
bundle install
```

Restart your application, open it, and launch developer console, and you should see it like this:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are a few configuration parameters that control whether SQL queries are printed to the log.

(This answer is based on Rails 6.0.)

First, confirm that the logger is configured and its `@logdev` has a `@dev` or `@filename` that matches your expectations.

```rb
pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Base.logger

=> #<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x00007fd47b400900
 ...,
 @logdev=
  #<Logger::LogDevice:0x00007fd47b400a90
   @binmode=false,
   @dev=#<File:log/development.log>,
   @filename="log/development.log",
   ...>,
 ...>
```

Next, ensure that the logger level is set to `DEBUG`:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.debug!
```

Try running a query to see whether the issue has been fixed:

```rb
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query 'SELECT 1'
  SQL (0.1ms)  SELECT 1
```

If queries are being printed to the log file (e.g. `log/development.log`) but not to the console, then you may need to do this:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.extend(
  ActiveSupport::Logger.broadcast(ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT))
)
```

If you're still not getting SQL queries, then the `ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber` may not be listening to events (e.g. because some libraries deactivate it). Activate it:

```rb
ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber.attach_to :active_record
```

Answer (score 4):

For Rails v"6.1.7.3" the following combination worked for me:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber.attach_to :active_record
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to set up logger level in `config/application.rb`:

```rb
config.after_initialize do
  Rails.logger.level = (ENV['LOG_LEVEL'] || Logger::INFO).to_i
end
```

On production my `ENV['LOG_LEVEL']` will be set to the value of `Logger::INFO` and on my local machine it'll be `Logger::DEBUG`.