# Ruby count number of queries to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is something I don't fully understand.
Look at this example which makes n calls (or queries) to database where n is number of customers.

```
@reports = Report.where(:car => car)

for customer in customers
  report = @reports.where(:city => customer.city, :age=> customer.age)
end
```

This one below just call the database once, right?

```
@reports = Report.where(:car => car).where( :city => customers.map(&:city), :age => customers.map(&:age))

for customer in customers
  report = @reports.detect(:city => customer.city, :age=> customer.age)
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I see the SQL that will be generated by a given ActiveRecord query in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344232/how-can-i-see-the-sql-that-will-be-generated-by-a-given-activerecord-query-in-ru)

Comment: Note: Nobody in the Ruby world uses `for`. This code is typically written as `customers.each do |customer|` instead.

Comment: You're on the right track, but if you have your relationships set up properly this could be as easy as `car.reports.where(...)` and have the same conditions in there.

Comment: @tadman thanks! I don't use it actually it was just for example

Comment: All 3 examples make `n +1` calls to the database (queries). `where` is a query method as is evidenced by the fact that it exists in `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods`

Comment: @engineersmnky what if i change second example to detect ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the second example just makes on call to the database.

When you do `@reports= Report.where(:car => car).where( :city => customers.map(&:city), :age => customers.map(&:age))`
 you are loading all those records into the `@reports` variable.

So at the detect part it doesn't need to call the database, since the records are already there.

Comment: it makes just one call because of map functions or because of detect functions?

Comment: The map is only used for filtering the results better. The `detect` function that is doing the job, it is looping the reports array, instead of querying the database.